# Filemaker dropdown not working

Tags: database, layout, filemaker

I've created a dropdown box in layout mode of filemaker and specified a field to pull in. However the box is remaining blank and not pulling in any of the information from the field in the table. What can have been missed for this to happen?

[image]

Comment: This question would be better asked in one of the forums dedicated to the FileMaker platform.

Comment: May be you source data is blank ? (Values from)
Also the Browse Mode should be checked. And may be you don't have any records on the current layouts table ?
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Di9qM.png)

Answer (score 0):

Most probably it is the problem with the value list set up or the relationship you are using to pull in the data for your drop-down.

If you are using a value list from a related data, place a portal based on the same relationship on the same layout and see if data comes through. If it does not - resolve your relationship first.

If you are pulling all values from a field in the same table, make sure in the value list setup you select the same relationship as the one the layout based on, the target field is selected and "Include all values" option is checked

Comment: How about if the table is independent of others. For example we currently sell products specified at certain types of vehicles. However this product would be a extra item at the basket for any type of vehicle, so is not specifically linked?

Comment: Of course - it will also work for the layout based on a different table, as long as value list is based on "Include all values". Tables do not have to be related.